# 2 by 2 Schur Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, schur-decomposition

Let $A$ be a real matrix 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w & x \\
    y & z
  \end{bmatrix}
with complex eigenvalues $a+bi$ and $a-bi$. We're looking for an algorithm to find the Givens rotation matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
    c & s \\
    -s & c
  \end{bmatrix}

such that we have

$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
c & s \\
-s & c
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b_1 \\
b_2 & a
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
c & -s \\
s & c
\end{array} \right] $$

where $b_1b_2 = -b^2$